# Updating to swift 3 JSON file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im updating my app to swift 3

I am getting a couple of errors

```
for (k, v): (AnyObject, AnyObject) in value {
```

Gets an NSDictionary.Iterator.Element is not convertable to (Anyobject, Anyobject)

Subsiquently Im getting this error

```
   var artworks = [Artwork]()
func loadInitialData() {
    // 1
    let fileName = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "PublicArt", ofType: "json");

    let data: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileName!), options: NSData.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))

    // 2
    var error: NSError?
    let jsonObject: AnyObject!
    do {
        jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data,
                    options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        jsonObject = nil
    }

    // 3
    if let jsonObject = jsonObject as? [String: AnyObject], error == nil,
        // 4
        let jsonData = JSONValue.fromObject(jsonObject)?["data"]?.array {
            for artworkJSON in jsonData {
                if let artworkJSON = artworkJSON.array,
                    // 5
                    let artwork = Artwork.fromJSON(artworkJSON) {
                        artworks.append(artwork)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

> JsonObject produces 'Any' not the expected contextual result type
>   'AnyObject'

and

> Argument type [String : AnyObject] does not conform to expected type
>   'AnyObject'

Im assuming this is an easy one but I havent coded in a year and would be very appreciative of the help

Thanks

Travis

**UPDATE**

So I just updated the code

but getting an error in the JSON.swift file

```
static func fromObject(_ object: AnyObject) -> JSONValue? {
    switch object {
    case let value as NSString:
      return JSONValue.jsonString(value as String)
    case let value as NSNumber:
      return JSONValue.jsonNumber(value)
    case _ as NSNull:
      return JSONValue.jsonNull
    case let value as NSDictionary:
      var jsonObject: [String:JSONValue] = [:]
      for (k, v): (AnyObject, AnyObject) in value {
        if let k = k as? NSString {
          if let v = JSONValue.fromObject(v) {
            jsonObject[k as String] = v
          } else {
            return nil
          }
        }
      }
      return JSONValue.jsonObject(jsonObject)
    case let value as NSArray:
      var jsonArray: [JSONValue] = []
      for v in value {
        if let v = JSONValue.fromObject(v as AnyObject) {
          jsonArray.append(v)
        } else {
          return nil
        }
      }
      return JSONValue.jsonArray(jsonArray)
    default:
      return nil
    }
  }

}
```

error is:

> nsdictionary.iterate.element '(aka (key: Any, value: Any)') is not
>   convertible to 'AnyObject, AnyObject)'

for code line

```
 for (k, v): (AnyObject, AnyObject) in value {
```

Sorry for the late reply

Regards

Travis

Comment: The errors in the second half are in //2 and //4 respectively

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much `AnyObject` aka *it's-an-object-but-I-don't-know-the-type*.

Since the JSON file is in your bundle you know exactly the types of all objects.

In Swift 3 a JSON dictionary is `[String:Any]` and a JSON array is `[[String:Any]]`.

However I don't know the exact structure of the JSON and I don't know what `JSONValue` does – a third party library is actually not necessary – but this might be a starting point to get the array for key `data`.

```
func loadInitialData() {

    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PublicArt", withExtension: "json")!

    do {
        let data =  try Data(contentsOf: fileURL, options: [])

        let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as! [String: Any]
        let jsonData = jsonObject["data"] as! [[String:Any]]
        for artworkJSON in jsonData {
            print(artworkJSON)
            // ... create Artwork items
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
        fatalError("This should never happen")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, ive just tried this. that worked but I still have an error in my JSON.swift file I just realised

Comment: Consider that the unspecified JSON type in Swift 3 is `Any`